# VBscript Create an object from an IE element

Tags: javascript, html, object, vbscript, element

I tried looking for an answer but to no avail. I hit a wall every time.
Maybe someone can help?

I'm trying to click on an element with VBscript on a website.
This works. However, first i want to check if the element exists with a loop.
This would work, if not for the "Invalid use of null" error i get with the code below.

How to create an object to check if it exists from an IE element?

```
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
IE.Navigate "url"
With IE.Document

Do
if not CreateObject(.getElementByID("formButton2343255")) is nothing then            
.getElementByID("formButton2343255").Click()
Exit Do
End if
WScript.Sleep 500 
Loop

SET objWshShell = Nothing
End With
End Function
```

I expect the button to be clicked. But either my object dont exist or i get invalid use of null in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code you posted in a custom script of mine and think I have figured a solution. To check if the element exists, you have to use the `IsObject` function; however, if you try to use it before the `DOM` is ready (i.e., `IE.ReadyState` is equal to `4`) it throws an unspecified error (typical of IE related things, lots and lots of quirks).

So, instead of using the infinite loop to wait until the element exists, I changed it to wait until the `DOM` gets ready; So, by the time I call `IsObject` it should not throw an error anymore, yielding the proper result therefore allowing the check to be made as expected.

The example bellow opens an IE window and navigate to https://stackoverflow.com; waits for the DOM to be ready and then click on the "Tags" menu on the left sidebar (`#nav-tags`); hence, navigates to the "Tags" page as expected. Very much like your example, so that you can easily use this as guide to figure your case.

```
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")

IE.Navigate "https://stackoverflow.com"
IE.Visible = True

'Wait til DOM is ready
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4 : Loop

If IsObject(IE.Document.GetElementById("nav-tags")) Then
    IE.Document.GetElementById("nav-tags").Click()
End If

Set IE = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply lenilsondc!

Well, when i do that, i get an error "object required".
Sorry, let me edit my original post with the full procedure including the WITH. Maybe i did something wrong there?

Comment: @MushroomKing are you running a vbs file or are you running VBScript inside the html page within a script tag?

Comment: Im using a vbs file.

Comment: @MushroomKing I've updated my answer, I think I got it this time. Check it out.

Comment: Great! Thats a better solution than what i came up with! I will use it. Thanks alot lot. 
I used "If IsNull(IE.Document.getElementByID("...") Then..."
Which also works in this case without error.

Comment: @MushroomKing yes, `IsNull` should also works after the DOM gets ready. Anyways, feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful, cheers :{D

Comment: It sure was :). Works great. Thank you.
Currently im really stuck on something related. I don't know if i should make new topic. But when i click the download button, i get a popup from internet security and have to click on "Allow". I tried to address the popup with PID, but it's embedded in the IE. :S not sure how to focus on it and how to "wait" for it to be loaded....

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible, but that would be a whole new question to ask on SO